# How to use for loop to identify variable names

Tags: python

```
second_canvas = 250*np.ones((300,300,3), dtype="uint8")
cv2_imshow(second_canvas)
cX1,cY1 = (second_canvas.shape[1]//2,0)
cX2,cY2 = (second_canvas.shape[1],second_canvas.shape[0]//2)
cX3,cY3 = (second_canvas.shape[1]//2,second_canvas.shape[0])

for i in range(1,4):
  cv2.circle(second_canvas, (cX'{}',cY'{}').format(i), 175,(0,255,0))

cv2_imshow(second_canvas)
```

As in here, I want for loop in order to use the respective variable. Can anyone help, please if there is a way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Any reason not to use a list of tuples to store your cX and cY values? For example: `xy = []` and then `xy.append((second_canvas.shape[1]//2,0))` etc. Then you can simply iterate over the list: `for x,y in xy:`

Comment: I wanted to know how to actually come with solution when faced with identical situation. What you told though, works perfect for the above case.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the list of variables:

```py
for i in [[cX1,cY1],[cX2,cY2],[cX3,cY3]]:
    cv2.circle(second_canvas, i[0],i[1], 175,(0,255,0))
```

You're not looping over the names of the variables but the variables themselves.  If you want to loop over the names of the variables and access them, you can use two functions, `locals()` and `globals()`.  It's more recommended to use `locals()` because it will return a `dict` of the local variables including the globals ones.

The locals variables are the ones defined and used inside a function.

Example:

```py
for i in zip("cX1 cX2 cX3".split(" "),"cY1 cY2 cY3".split(" ")):
    cv2.circle(second_canvas, locals()[i[0]],locals()[i[1]],175,(0,255,0))
```

or

```py
for i in zip("cX1 cX2 cX3".split(" "),"cY1 cY2 cY3".split(" ")):
    cv2.circle(second_canvas, globals()[i[0]],globals()[i[1]],175,(0,255,0))
```

depending if it's inside a function (`locals()`) or not (`globals()`).

Comment: see the documentation here : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can just use two lists like this:

```
cX, cY = [None] * 3, [None] * 3
cX[0],cY[0] = (second_canvas.shape[1]//2,0)
cX[1],cY[1] = (second_canvas.shape[1],second_canvas.shape[0]//2)
cX[2],cY[2] = (second_canvas.shape[1]//2,second_canvas.shape[0])

for i in range(0,3):
  cv2.circle(second_canvas, (cX[i],cY[i]).format(i), 175,(0,255,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get variables by their names with `globals()` function. So you will be getting all the instantiated variables in your code and selecting the ones that you need by their name:

```
variable1 = [1, 2]
print(globals()["variable" + "1"])
```

**Output:** [1, 2]

In your case, I think this would be your solution:

```
cv2.circle(second_canvas, (globals()["cX" + str(i)],globals()["cX" + str(i)]).format(i), 175,(0,255,0))
```